# When setting up a state machine in the AWS CDK, how do you remove the default Retry policy for a Lambda Invocation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions, retrypolicy

I'm creating a state machine with the AWS CDK. Instead of the default retry policy, which looks like this:

```
  "Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "Lambda.ServiceException",
        "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
        "Lambda.SdkClientException"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 2,
      "MaxAttempts": 6,
      "BackoffRate": 2
    }
  ]
```

I want to have only one catch-all policy that looks like this:

```
"Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "States.ALL"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 10,
      "MaxAttempts": 3,
      "BackoffRate": 1.5
    }
  ]
```

Unfortunately I can't find a way to remove the default policy when deploying the stack. My catch-all simply gets added to the end of the Retry policy array.

```
"Retry": [
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "Lambda.ServiceException",
        "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
        "Lambda.SdkClientException"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 2,
      "MaxAttempts": 6,
      "BackoffRate": 2
    },
    {
      "ErrorEquals": [
        "States.ALL"
      ],
      "IntervalSeconds": 10,
      "MaxAttempts": 3,
      "BackoffRate": 1.5
    }
  ]
```

Anyone know how to get rid of the default policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-stepfunctions-tasks/lambdainvokeprops.html#aws_stepfunctions_tasks_LambdaInvokeProps)
There is a flag you can set when you create the LambdaInvoke task called `retryOnServiceExceptions`. Setting that to false removes the default retry policy.

```
var submitOrder = new sfnt.LambdaInvoke(this, "SubmitOrder", {
  lambdaFunction: submitOrderLambda,
  comment: "Call the orders api to submit the order update",
  retryOnServiceExceptions: false   
});
```

Comment: Do you know how to overwrite it with a custom retry logic ?